# Assigning value to image in CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css, properties

I'm using javascript, html and css to make a math game. I made a CSS class for each number (0-9) and all it has is a background property that gives an image of that number. I want to add the numbers up but I can't since they're just images. Is there a way to assign a number value to the CSS number class? Or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Please paste your code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using divs for the images

HTML

```
<div data-value="1" class="img one" /> 
<div data-value="2" class="img two" />
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
   var sum = 0
   $('.img').each(function(){
       sum += $(this).data('value');
   })

   alert(sum)   
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p6vkp91o/1/

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your code so we can take a look?

Also css id's and classes can only start with with an underscore (_), a hyphen (-), or a letter(a–z).  Not a number.

For what you are trying to do, look into data attributes.  http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/